# How to add Syntax and/or Parameters to an already created topic in Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-editor

I have explored the new *Documentation* and found a topic with a few nice examples. However, I felt that some examples needed some more explanation about syntax and stuff then I went to add info to another section (*Syntax* maybe) but I couldn't find a way to add it.

I know I could edit the example or propose a change, but I feel that it wouldn't fit mixed with the code and I couldn't think about a way to put that explanation in there.

I see that I can make *Syntax* and *Parameters* sections in new topics, but I couldn't find a way to make it in already created topics. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the '+' icon on the right. It's possible this is way too subtle and needs updated styling. *Sigh, beta.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see, however the said topic doesn't show a Syntax and Parameters section like in your image (it has only Examples, Remarks and Versions), then neither does that 'plus' sign. Maybe I can't see it due some perms or reputation barrier? The said topic, just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/delphi/599/hello-world

Comment: @Shadow ah, that's a special overview topic for the tag that contains version information. There is only one topic like this one per tag.

Comment: ah I see. But if I got it right, does it mean that overview topics cannot have a Syntax section, per example? Or am I missing something? The 'tour' thing didn't seem to be much clear about the topic sections by the way.

Comment: Ok, after checking other new topics there (like http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/delphi/2443/passing-information-between-multiple-forms-within-application) I noticed they have those sections while that overview topic does not.

Then replying to my own question, yeah, overview topics doesn't seem to have Syntax and Parameters sections (no idea why though).

Anyway, this awswer didn't help me to achieve what I wanted, but answered the question. I'm going to accept it, thanks again.